# send request to method using ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

I have a website that contains an email address. I have a webpage that is getting email id. Now I have to send the email id to the web service using ajax. How can I do this? 
The code below is placed at aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".submit-btn").click(function () {
        var _Email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;
        alert(_Email);
        $.ajax({
            url: "service/orderit.asmx/SendEmail",
            data: {_email:_Email}
        });
        //PageMethod("/service/orderit.asmx/SendEmail", ['_email', _Email])
    });
```

The code below is in the web service.

```
public json_helper.GenericJS SendEmail(string _email)
{
    json_helper.GenericJS retval = new json_helper.GenericJS();

    return retval;
}
```

This web service is in `service` folder and the page name is `orderit.asmx`.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want webservice can Return JSON

you need add a attribute on your WebService

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetJsonContext(){

  // delcare some object 

  Car myCar = new Car();
  myCar.color="RED";


  //Return Json

  return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myCar)
}
```

And if you want post JSON to webservice

in webservice , you need create a object that construct is like your json format

like : {name:'Aaron',age:'18',sex:'boy'}  . and in your WebService need create a object has name、age、sex property

ex: add a struct

```
 public struct Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
    }
```

and in WebService Method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string InputJsonContext(Person p){

  //do a some process

   string inputname = p.name;

//etc ...

}
```

Javascript :

```
 $.ajax({
                  url: "service/orderit.asmx/InputJsonContext",
                  data: {name:'Aaron',age:'18',sex:'boy'} 
              });
```